# Http DELETE with empty body

Tags: http, elm

In Elm (0.18) I'm calling one http DELETE endpoint that if successful responds with 200 and an empty body.

In this case (of success) I need to pass back a message with the initial id (`OnDelete playerId`). But as the body is empty i can't parse it from there.

Currently I'm doing it like this, but is there a more elegant way to write the `expect` part of `Http.Request`:

```
Http.expectStringResponse (\response -> Ok playerId)
```

?

This reflects my current code:

```
deletePlayer : PlayerId -> Cmd Msg
deletePlayer playerId =
    deleteRequest playerId
        |> Http.send OnDelete


deleteRequest : PlayerId -> Http.Request PlayerId
deleteRequest playerId =
    Http.request
        { body = Http.emptyBody

        , expect = Http.expectStringResponse (\response -> Ok playerId)

        , headers = []
        , method = "DELETE"
        , timeout = Nothing
        , url = "http://someHost/players/" ++ playerId
        , withCredentials = False
        }


type alias PlayerId =
    String
```

Answer (score 5):

Elm v0.19 added [`expectWhatever`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/http/2.0.0/Http#expectWhatever). It behaves slightly different with the `Result` being checked for errors, but a similar effect.

---

I've created a helper `expectUnit` for "empty" 200 responses.

```
expectUnit : Expect ()
expectUnit =
    Http.expectStringResponse << always <| Ok ()



deleteThing : String -> Request ()
deleteThing path =
    Http.request
        { method = "DELETE"
        , headers = []
        , url = "http://localhost/api"
        , body = Http.jsonBody <| Encode.object [ ( "path", Encode.string path ) ]
        , expect = expectUnit
        , timeout = Nothing
        , withCredentials = False
        }
```

But for you, the *best* you could get is.

```
{ ...
, expect = Http.expectStringResponse << always <| Ok playerId
...
}
```

Or you could create a helper (which is actually the `singleton` or `pure` for `Expect`)

```
alwaysExpect : a -> Expect a
alwaysExpect =
     Http.expectStringResponse << always << Ok
```

Which could be used like

```
{ ...
, expect = alwaysExpect playerId
...
}
```

Comment: i like your alwaysExpect wrapper method although it saddens me that there isn't such thing out of box. I'll mark it as correct answer if in few days if nobody will provide a better answer.

Comment: Http v2.0.0's [`expectWhatever`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/http/2.0.0/Http#expectWhatever) now does this, although the name is not my favorite.